# How to read properties file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

How to read `config.properties` file using shell script?

Example file:

```
key1 = This is 1st value

key2 = this is 2nd value

key3
```

1. Display all key and values.
2. How to check which key don't have value?
3. Enter any key that key related value display.

Comment: How are you going to use this data and what have you tried?

Comment: what do you want to read from this file?

Comment: What is the layout of `config.properties`? This will determine how it will be read. Are the keys in config.properties arranged such that `key1` will always be line 1 and nowhere else? Are the keys in `config.properties` associated with a value in `key=value` format? Give us more information.

Comment: I'm guessing the third question wants to mean "how do I obtain the value of a given key?" but it's too unclear to actually make that edit.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Read configuration into an associative array
declare -A CONFIG
# IFS is the 'internal field separator'. In this case, your file uses '='
IFS="="
while read -r key value
do
    if [ -n $value ]; then
        CONFIG[$key]=$value
    else
        CONFIG[$key]=$value
    fi
done < YOUR_CONFIG_FILENAME
unset IFS

# If a parameter is passed, look it up by that, else print everything.
if [ $1 ]; then
    if [ -n ${CONFIG[$1]} ]; then
        echo "Key: $1, Value: ${CONFIG[$1]}"
    else
        echo "The key '$1' does not exist"
    fi
else
    for key in "${!CONFIG[@]}"; do
        if [ -n ${CONFIG[$key]} ]; then
            echo "Key: $key, Value: ${CONFIG[$key]}"
        else
            echo "Key: $key has no value"
        fi
    done
fi

exit $?
```

It will read in all keynames in the config file and inform you if no value is set against the key, meeting (1) and (2) of your requirements.

I don't quite understand what the requirements are for (3) though

"3) enter any key that key related value display"
Update the script with that requirement.

Comment: Though with `IFS="="` any whitespace around the equals sign becomes significant.

Comment: Also, why are you trimming double quotes from the value?  The example doesn't show any double quotes in the values, and if there were any, perhaps they would be significant, too.

Comment: I had double quotes some of the variables in my env file, which I used for testing. But yes, whitespace is an issue with IFS. OP can always pad it out or use another format.

Comment: user enter key then display value

Comment: How to change the value, which one user want

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. its also contain database operations:you can get all answers that you wanted if you clearly understood this code

```
  #!/bin/bash
    PROPERTY_FILE=filename.properties

    function getProperty {
       PROP_KEY=$1
       PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "$PROP_KEY" | cut -d'=' -f2`
       echo $PROP_VALUE
    }

    echo "# Reading property from $PROPERTY_FILE"
    DB_USER=$(getProperty "db.username")
    DB_PASS=$(getProperty "db.password")
    ROOT_LOC=$(getProperty "root.location")
    echo $DB_USER
    echo $DB_PASS
    echo $ROOT_LOC
    echo "Writing on DB ... "
    mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASS dbname<<EOFMYSQL

    update tablename set tablename.value_ = "$ROOT_LOC" where tablename.name_="Root directory location";
    EOFMYSQL
    echo "Writing root location($ROOT_LOC) is done ... "
    counter=`mysql -u${DB_USER} -p${DB_PASS} dbname -e "select count(*) from tablename where tablename.name_='Root directory location' and tablename.value_ = '$ROOT_LOC';" | grep -v "count"`;

    if [ "$counter" = "1" ]
    then
    echo "ROOT location updated"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of the (bash) [script I use in my projects](https://github.com/chalaev/el-backup/blob/master/common.sh):

```
# reading CONFIG FILE
# usage: readConf <fileName> <several variable names>
function readConf {
local confFile=$1
shift
local allowedVars="$@" # only specified variable names will be processed
local forbidden=" #@%*()<>~'\"{}[]\$"

for VN in $allowedVars; do
    unset $VN
done

while IFS== read -r key val ; do
    var=${key//["$forbidden"]}
    if [[ " ${allowedVars[@]} " =~ " $var " ]]; then
    val=${val//["$forbidden"]}
    eval "${var}=\"${val}\""
    else
    if ! [ -z $var ]; then
        echo "conf parameter: \"$var\" is not supposed to be defined in \"$confFile\""
    fi
    fi
done < <(grep -v "^#" $confFile)
}
```

It scans config file (first argument) for specified parameters (remaining arguments). Certain "forbidden symbols" are ignored to avoid code injections. Lines starting with '#' are ignored.